# How to drop Postgres constraint if table exists?

Tags: sql, postgresql, constraints

How can I drop *fk_bar* if its table *tbl_foo* exists in Postgres and if the constraint itself exists?

I tried

```
ALTER TABLE IF EXISTS tbl_foo DROP CONSTRAINT IF EXISTS fk_bar;
```

But that gave me an error when tbl_foo does not exist. It executes successfully if the table does exist.

Comment: Works for me. Which Postgres version are you using? (use `select version()` to find out)

Comment: PostgreSQL 9.0.13

Comment: Actually -- I have another server with 9.2.x and it works there

Answer (score 2):

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-altertable.html

```
ALTER TABLE [ IF EXISTS ] [ ONLY ] name [ * ]
```

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-altertable.html

```
ALTER TABLE [ ONLY ] name [ * ]
```

before 9.2 no such syntaxis:

```
ALTER TABLE IF EXISTS
```

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/release-9-2.html

> Add IF EXISTS options to some ALTER commands (Pavel Stehule)